# Mesos Failed to connect error to IP:5050

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

I am new to Mesos and just finished setting up mesos and along with zookeeper on my test server.

Unfortunately I keep getting this error message on my mesos console indicating i am unable to connect to mesos on port 5050 and can't seem to figure out why.

I have included the error in the screen shot below

The mesos log files doesn't point to why the error is showing either.

[image]

Comment: check if this port is open on your machine  [netstat -aonp]

Comment: Firewall is turned off and yes netstat does show a service listening on that port

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the problem by this:

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=x.x.x.x --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --hostname=x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 3):

We can avoid this problem by starting mesos-master with following option:

```
--ip=xx.xx.xx.xx --hostname_lookup=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem. Open the web page in Chrome, and open the developer tool, you will see the chrome is accessing the web site with domain, in my case the domain name is "mesosphere", as there is no mesosphere in dns, so the accessing was failed.

[image]

I solved the problem by adding the mesosphere in the hosts file, `C:/windows/system32/etc/hosts/`

If you use the domain name for the Mesos cluster you must set the domain name in windows hosts.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issues here.

- Is your mesos-master running and healthy ?
- Has leader election process completed, if all is good.

Check if you are able to do

```
ping leader.mesos
```

If above ping doesn't work, that means leader has not been elected. First fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. Luckily, I have a running mesos server also. So, I can compare the different between my demo and the running mesos server. I captured the packets between client and server in my demo. I found the explorer didn`t resend fresh request, only some keepalive packets.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INRtT.jpg]

but, when I catch the packets in the running mesos server, I found the explorer send get request frequently. like the image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnWNB.jpg]

I think, if you run some task or add some agent, maybe it will activate the explore to send request frequently. Then the "Failed to connect" will disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues and what fixed it for me was the zookeeper configuration.  In my case I was using the EC2 public IP Address rather than the private one.  Once I changed the /etc/mesos/zk file to ***zk://<private IP>:2181/mesos*** I was able to connect without the constant error messages.  In other words, zookeeper was reporting to be running in one IP and mesos-master was trying to connect using a different IP.

Answer (score 0):

```
My configuration was correct as suggested. But failed to start mesos-master service. But There is alternative way to start mesos-master node with exact same configuration. Commands to start mesos-master

$ cd /usr/sbin   [or mesos_installation directory/bin]
$sudo ./mesos-master --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --log_dir=/home/rajeev/logs/mesos/

Its start mesos-master service successfully for me.
```